# Delete row using command name in gridview

Tags: c#-4.0

I am trying to delete a row using CommandName, but can't delete it. Please give me an idea how to do so.

gridview is bind with inner join query, so how could I delete a row?

I have tried this:

```
protected void Gridview1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "removeRow")
    {
        int picID = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        GridView1.DeleteRow(picID);
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }      
}
```

In gridview query I have added this:

```
str = "select * from Products INNER JOIN orders on Products.picID=orders.productID";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
con.Open();
```

Comment: I can't understand the second code block where you have added?

Comment: on page load where i have used gridview.databind()

Comment: by piece of your code `GridView1.DeleteRow(picID)` the record is not deleted physically from the database, it is just removed from the `GridViewRowCollection`.If you want to remove it from database you have to write delete query and execute it in `Gridview1_RowCommand`event.

Comment: i have wrote delete query but its not working.

Comment: so i have this gridview which shows data of products table,and if i wants to delete row, i have to delete a row from another table named orders table ,and when i write query to delete row in orders table it shows error that this datakeyname do not exists in currunt gridview

Comment: Where you have written this delete query can you show it?

Comment: IF you want to remove row from gridview and not from database then ask accordingly.

Comment: sorry its wrong but i have no idea,i tried this  ,what to do with pic i used ?

                 if (e.CommandName == "removeRow")
{
 int pic = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
ViewState["orderID"] = pic;
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("connectionstring");
string str;
str = "delete from orders where orderID='"+pic+"'";
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
sda.Fill(ds);
ViewState["ds"] = ds;
GridView1.DataSource = ds;
GridView1.DataBind();
con.Close();   
 }